# AWK to read multiple files in linux without duplicates

Tags: linux, unix, files, awk

I have a task to merge three files in linux, so i used awk to achieve this task.
hostsfiles is a variable which has test.txt test1.txt and test3.txt

```
awk 1 {{ hostsfiles | join(' ') }}
```

I get below error. How do i avoid the error when any one of the file is missing

```
fatal: cannot open file `/test.txt' for reading (No such file or directory
```

Comment: Look for files with e.g. `find` and remove the ones that don't exist from your list prior to launching your command.

Comment: How about using cat command to merge all your files? ```cat $hostfsfiles > targetfile``` If any file is not present, it will be automatically ignored and it's output be printed to console.